# Can Create Adaptive payment on paypal pro request

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I want to know if I can split amount request on a paypal pro request. I use PayPal_base.dll and create DoDirectPaymentRequest or DoExpressCheckoutPaymentRequest. But I want to know if I can split or use Adaptive Payment to send money in two different account.

Answer (score 0):

You can use adaptive payments to split the payments using Express Checkout, but not with DoDirectPayment.

Here is some info on setting up adaptive: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-basicChainedPayment-curl-etc/

and the Express Checkout guide: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/gs_expresscheckout/